# Change data source from Pivot

Tags: excel, vba, pivot-table, objectdatasource, listobject

I am creating a new file based on an old one and now I am trying to change the data source from a pivot chart (still linked to the old file). The new data source should be from a table on the new workbook. Can you please help?

```
    Dim pt As PivotTable
    Dim MyData As Excel.ListObject
    
    Set MyData = Application.Range(Europe).ListObject
    
For Each pt In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Chart - City").PivotTables
         pt.ChangePivotCache ActiveWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create _
            (SourceType:=xlDatabase, SourceData:="MyData")
Next pt
```

Answer (score 0):

The *SourceData* parameter for the *PivotCaches.Create* method expects a **string**, not a listobject.

Try with:

`SourceData:=MyData.Name`

Comment: Thank you a lot for your help. I tried but still got an error on the:
Set MyData = Application.Range(Europe).ListObject
Do you know why?

Comment: I wouldn't know since you haven't shared the definition of 'Europe'.

Comment: Sorry, Europe is the name of a table

Comment: In that case everything seems fine to me, sorry.